# Probability of coin heads

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Four fair coins are flipped. If the outcomes are assumed independent, what is the probability that two heads and two tails are obtained?

I calculated the answer as $\frac{11}{16}$ via using brute-force computations; is there any logical approach for this?

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer is $\frac6{16}$. In general, for $n$ fair coins and obtaining $k$ heads and $n-k$ tails the probability is $\binom nk/2^n$.

Comment: @rasul_rza24 Following Pascal's triangle, letting $p \in (0,1)$, and letting $q = (1 - p)$, you can apply binomial expansion.  $$1^n = (p + q)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$$  In effect, you have $(n + 1)$ terms, and each term represents the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads, as $k$ ranges from $0$ through $n$, inclusive.  Note that $\binom{n}{k}$ is actually the $k$-th element across in the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle.  Parcly Taxel's answer is (in general) consistent with  $p = q = (1/2),$ and specifically consistent with $n = 4$.

Comment: For being first (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You would have
$$P=\frac{\mbox{good cases}}{\mbox{total cases}}=\frac{\frac{4!}{2!2!}}{\sum_{i=0}^4\frac{4!}{i!(4-i)!}}=\frac{6}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

The number $X$ of Heads in four independent tosses of fair coins has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4, p=1/2).$ You seek
$P(X = 2) = {4 \choose 2}(1/2)^4 = 6/16 =  0.375
 \ne 11/16.$

In R statistical software, where `dbinom` is a binomial PDF:

```
dbinom(2, 4, .5)
[1] 0.375
```

By 'brute force' listing:

```
TTTT
TTTH, TTHT, THTT, HTTT
TTHH, THTH, HTTH, HHTT, HTHT, THHT
HHHT, HHTH, HTHH, THHH
HHHH
```

You want the third row.